# How can I avoid SQL injection in this EF Core query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Since EF Core does not currently execute group by queries in the database, I'm using the following query to get the job done (`InvoiceQuery` is a `DbQuery` type):

```
long merchantId = 177;
var invTokens = new List<string> {"qasas", "efsac"};
string inClause = string.Join(",", invTokens);

string query = $@"SELECT i.Token, i.Balance, COALESCE(SUM(i.Amount), 0) AS ProcessingAmount
                  FROM inv.Invoices i
                  WHERE i.Token IN ({inClause})
                    AND i.MerchantId = {merchantId} 
                    AND i.Status = {(int)InvoiceStatus.Scheduled}
                  GROUP BY i.Token, i.Balance";

return await dbContext.InvoicesQuery.FromSql(query).ToListAsync();
```

The above code runs perfect but I don't like it because it gives me a warning of a 'Possible SQL injection vulnerability'.. I know I can use a `#pragma` to suppress this warning (that's what I'm currently using).

I have tried passing the query and provide the params to the `FromSql` method, and that works but the parameter that goes into the `IN` clause is not getting correctly mapped..

Tried using  `$"'{string.Join("', '", invTokens)}'"` but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL here anyway? It's not a complex query, you could do this with Linq.

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql ? It shows how to pass parameters safely (in multiple different ways).

Comment: `The above code runs perfect` I am honestly surprised the query runs successfully, given you aren't quoting the individual `inClause` values. What is the **exact** value of `query` at runtime?

Comment: @DavidG as i said, group by queries are currently not executed in the db (they are executed in memory)

Comment: EF Core does support group by, but you need to use v2.1 or newer.

Comment: @mjwills yep, but couldn't find an example that passes a list in a ``IN`` query

Comment: @DavidG o: you are right, i was thinking that group by support will be added in the 3.0 release. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Since EF Core 2.0, you can use a FormattableString, where you can use string interpolation for queries.
[String interpolation in FromSql and ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#string-interpolation-in-fromsql-and-executesqlcommand)
 [FormattableString Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring)

> In EF Core 2.0 we added special support for interpolated strings to our two primary APIs that accept raw SQL strings: `FromSql` and `ExecuteSqlCommand`. This new support allows C# string interpolation to be used in a 'safe' manner.

The example from the docs:

```
var city = "London";
var contactTitle = "Sales Representative";

using (var context = CreateContext())
{
    context.Set<Customer>()
        .FromSql($@"
            SELECT *
            FROM ""Customers""
            WHERE ""City"" = {city} AND
                ""ContactTitle"" = {contactTitle}")
            .ToArray();
 }
```

This will produce:

```
@p0='London' (Size = 4000)
@p1='Sales Representative' (Size = 4000)

SELECT *
FROM ""Customers""
WHERE ""City"" = @p0
    AND ""ContactTitle"" = @p1
```